Amplify IAM Authorisation auto signing Rest API request not working
I'm trying to make an API request to amplify backend referring to Amplify V6 documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/nextjs/build-a-backend/restapi/set-up-rest-api/#make-a-post-request
I have performed successful login using Amplify social provider login, and the cookies are being stored in the browser.
When I make an API call, the authorisation header, and not getting automatically signed into the API request.
const callPostApi = async ({
  url,
  payload,
}: CallPostApiType): Promise<RestApiResponse> => {
  try {
    const data = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
      nextServerContext: { cookies },
      operation: async (contextSpec) => {
        const authToken = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);
        return post({
          apiName: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_API_ENDPOINT_NAME as string,
          path: `${url}`,
          options: {
            headers: {
              "x-api-key": atob(
                process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_API_API_KEY as string
              ),
              Authorization: authToken.tokens?.idToken?.toString()!,
            },
            body: payload,
          },
        });
      },
    });
    return data.response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

My API fails with the following error:

IncompleteSignatureException: Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter.
Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.
Authorization=eyJraWQiOiJRQU5NWTB2N0xZdkZSSFpTOWR6M

Amplify API are supposed to automatically sign the request with AWS Signature, but in this case, it doesn't seem to be happening. I'm using V6 version of AWS amplify. It works perfectly fine in Amplify V5 version, that the API request is automatically signed. But for my current use case I need to use aws-amplify v6.

Can anyone please let me know the correct way, I tried lots of things, stil not able to figure out the issue
